# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm doing a maven project，and my IDE is Eclipse。What I cannot grasp is when I use “clean -X” in Eclipse，it will report the following error：

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 16:44:56+0800)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: EUC_CN
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/lingxiubo/Documents/maven/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/lingxiubo/Documents/maven/repo
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /Users/lingxiubo/Documents/maven/repo
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.soft:soft-enrol:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging war from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: org.soft:soft-enrol:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building soft-enrol Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       org.soft:soft-enrol:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release, releases+snapshots), spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone, releases+snapshots), JBoss Repo (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases, releases+snapshots), people.apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/, snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/, snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <directory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <excludeDefaultDirectories default-value="false">${clean.excludeDefaultDirectories}</excludeDefaultDirectories>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <followSymLinks default-value="false">${clean.followSymLinks}</followSymLinks>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <reportDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${clean.skip}</skip>
  <testOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <verbose>${clean.verbose}</verbose>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ soft-enrol ---
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@424b29cf]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) directory = /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target
[DEBUG]   (f) excludeDefaultDirectories = false
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) followSymLinks = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) reportDirectory = /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/site
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) testOutputDirectory = /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/test-classes
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Deleting /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target
[INFO] Deleting directory /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/test-classes
[INFO] Deleting dangling symlink /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/soft-enrol/resource/image/login/?????? 1011_theme_asia.jpg
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.332s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Aug 04 15:10:46 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/101M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project soft-enrol: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/soft-enrol/resource/image/login/?????? 1011_theme_asia.jpg -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project soft-enrol: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/soft-enrol/resource/image/login/?????? 1011_theme_asia.jpg
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/soft-enrol/resource/image/login/?????? 1011_theme_asia.jpg
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute(CleanMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/soft-enrol/resource/image/login/?????? 1011_theme_asia.jpg
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute(CleanMojo.java:168)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

But when I use the terminal operation `mvn clean`, it works.

Comment: Its rude to walk away and not accept the answer. Siddhi is used by very few in the community, you should be really happy with a answer.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like there is a symlink in your project which eclipse cannot delete ( search the above for 'dangling symlink') . Try deleting the file manually once and also check it's permissions.

From command line which user do you run 'mvn clean' as ?

By the 'file' I mean the jpg file listed just before the clean fails.

`Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/lingxiubo/Desktop/chenyl/soft-enrol/target/soft-enrol/resource/image/login/?????? 1011_theme_asia.jpg`

**Update**

Finally, it turned out that there were some special characters in one of the file names which were causing Eclipse' maven to hiccup.

Comment: Are there some special characters in the jpg file which is not being deleted ?

Comment: Wow, you're terrific ah~~there is a file named by Chiese and number...I delete it manually and the eclipse can run!! thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Some times if any of the html file opened in browser and with noticing that if you do mvn clean.... it is giving same error.

So make sure to close all reports files from browsers. and then do clean.

Comment: actually in mycase the web project was already running on jetty, if stop the server and do mvn clean, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

cause
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project ****Project: Failed to clean project:project Failed to delete

method: 
The Java. Exe to take up the project of a jar file.
Solutions and enable the task manager to Java. Exe, perform cleanup again can

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I realized I had in use the folder described by such error by another program (a.k.a file explorer, terminal).
Once closed this another program, the project compiled right.