# Spring Boot, maven compile error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have this error when I try to create a jar package in my spring boot application. I inserted in Command line mvn clean install and I have this error. Project was created using Spring Initializr in Intelijj IDEA Ultimate.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.888 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-23T17:42:55+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) on project booking: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete E:\Documents\Java Projects\Spring Boot 101\target\surefire-reports -> [Help 1]
```

My POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>booking</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>booking</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I restarted maven using -X  -X switch to enable full debug logging.

> [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.

Comment: There's an earlier discussion of problems with maven clean here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649509/maven-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-5cle/28649877#28649877

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow below steps when any maven build is failing:
1) Go to command prompt and write this command: mvn clean install -DskipTests
2) Go back to Spring Boot, press Alt+F5 (or update the project).
3) Click on project and run as Maven install (Check also in deployment descriptor, if Maven Dependency is included).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you really interested in running your test. Delete test file from /src/test/java and then build.

Comment: Thank you Shirsh Sinha, ": mvn clean install -DskipTests" works for me, Problem is solved !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below configuration to spring-boot-maven-plugin in pom.xml

```
           <configuration>
                <mainClass>{Your_App_SpringBoot_StartupClass}</mainClass>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: I posted it, and in console i found some new errors

Comment: @DanielFlink, Those were tests failures, but your original issue got resolved with my answer. Kindly accept/upvote my answer, so it would be helpful for other users to locate the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the "repackage" goal in your build.?
repackage: create a jar or war file that is auto-executable. It can replace the regular artifact or can be attached to the build lifecycle with a separate classifier.

If you dont need it then what you can do is remove the goal part and try to execute it.

Keep the build simple :

```
**<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>**
```

If you need repackaging then you can try it from the commandline as given below :

**mvn package spring-boot:repackage**

Or,
You can delete the existing target folder manually and try it again.

Comment: did you try to delete the target folder manually any then building the project?

Comment: No results  
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   BookingApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Application...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

Answer (score 0):

Update plugin code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>romanian.coder</groupId>
    <artifactId>booking</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>booking</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>BookingApplicationTest</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I found new errors in console

```
ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 19.52 s <<< FAILURE! - in romanian.coder.booking.BookingApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(romanian.coder.booking.BookingApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   BookingApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Application...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```